# C - Prog crash exec

Tags: c

My program crash after displayed  "Quel est ce mot ?" : 
How I can foud, how I can resolve this ? 
Looking forwards your comments : ) 
Thank's for your help !

```
/* ************************************************************************** */
/*                                                                            */
/*                                                        :::      ::::::::   */
/*   main.c                                             :+:      :+:    :+:   */
/*                                                    +:+ +:+         +:+     */
/*   By: wjean-ma <marvin@42.fr>                    +#+  +:+       +#+        */
/*                                                +#+#+#+#+#+   +#+           */
/*   Created: 2015/08/03 03:07:53 by wjean-ma          #+#    #+#             */
/*   Updated: 2015/08/08 21:43:49 by wjean-ma         ###   ########.fr       */
/*                                                                            */
/* ************************************************************************** */

#include "include/libft.h"

char    *ft_putword(char **client, char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if ((*client)[i] != str[i])
            (*client)[i] = '*';
        else
            (*client)[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    return (*client);
}

int     main(void)
{
    char    *to_find;
    char    *client;
    int     size;
    int     buffer;

    to_find     = "Violet";
    size        = ft_strlen(to_find) + 1;
    if ((client = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size))) == NULL)
        return (-1);

    client = "******";
    while (ft_strcmp(client, to_find) != 0)
    {
        ft_putstr("Quel est ce mot: ");
        ft_putstr(ft_putword(&client, to_find));
        ft_putstr("\n> ");
        scanf("%s", client);
        while ((buffer = getchar()) != '\n')
            ;
        ft_putstr(ft_putword(&client, to_find));
        ft_putchar('\n');
    }
    ft_putstr("Done\n");
    free(client);
    return (0);
}
```

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */

Comment: How to find: Use a debugger!

Comment: Use the  `gdb` debugger

Comment: This is gonna be attempting to modify RO memory again:(  Debugger?  Absolutely!

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends! C in **not** C++! And note there is no use in taking `sizeof(char)`. It will never yield anything else than`1` as that is defined by the standard.

Comment: the call to malloc only allocates 7 bytes of memory.  However, the string "*******" is 8 bytes long (including the string terminator byte '\0')  So, even if the string is properly copied into the allocated memory, it will overrun the allocated memory, resulting in heap corruption.  which is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding this line: 'client = "******";'    'client' is a pointer to an array of allocated memory.   "*******" results in a pointer to readonly memory,  so the original contents of 'client' are overlayed with a pointer into readonly memory.  which results in a memory leak.  What is actually needed is: 'strcpy( client, "******" );'

Answer (score 1):

This statement: `client = "******";` sets `client` to the address of the string literal, which the compiler puts in read only memory. Then when you try to change this memory with `scanf("%s", client);` it will cause a crash.

You could initialize the client as an array like: `char client[] = "******";` so the compiler will put it in a write-able memory segment.

Comment: Et `scanf %s` à undefined behaviour when the buffer is exhausted; prefer `fgets`.